# Passing screenProps to in TabNavigator

Tags: react-native, tabnavigator

I'm new to React Native. I tried to pass a fetched data to my tab screens using screenProps. However, when I tried to call the data from my screen using this.props.ScreenProps my screens couldn't get the data. Can you look at my code and correct my mistakes?

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

TabNavigator:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Platform } from 'react-native'
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { TabNavigator, TabBarBottom } from 'react-navigation';

export default class RecentPage extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      title: 'Recent'
    }
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: null,
      page: 1,
      serviceId: 0,
      stateId: 0,
    }
  }
  param = "?page=" + this.state.page + "&serviceId=" + this.state.serviceId + "&stateId=" + this.state.stateId
  (console.log(param))
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("param", param)
    fetch(`${COMMON_APP.HOST_API}/api/Request/GetAllRequest${param}`)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status != 200) {
          throw new Error("not valid");
        }
        this.setState({ data: response.json() })
        console.log("data",this.state.data)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          alert("We have error!")
        }, 3000)
      });
  }
  render() {
    // const MOCK_DATA = this.state.data
    // return MOCK_DATA
    return(
    <TabNav
      screenProps={{data: this.state.data}}
      {...this.props}
      {...console.log("data:",this.state.data)}
    />
    )
  }

}
```

Here is one of my screens:

```
export default class MapTabItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const {screenProps} = this.props; 
    this.state = {
      location: { coords: { latitude: 20.1291, longitude: 105.3131 } },
      markers: screenProps.data,
      //markers: MOCK_DATA,
      region: {
        latitude: 20.1291,
        longitude: 105.3131,
        latitudeDelta: 0.1,
        longitudeDelta: 0.1 * ASPECT_RATIO,
      },
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this._getLocationAsync();
    console.log("marker:", this.state.markers)
    // the markers is undefined
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> ParentComponent

```
import React from 'react';
import ChildrenComponent from "./ChildrenComponent";

export default class MotherComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ChildrenComponent whichQuery="Child2ComponentMutationQuery" />
    );
  }
}
```

> ChildrenComponent

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import GrandsonComponent from "./GrandsonComponent";

export default class ChildrenComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {

        const {whichQuery} = this.props;
        console.log('From Mother:', whichQuery);

        return (
            <View><Text>{whichQuery}</Text></View>
        );
    };

    ChildrenComponent.propTypes = {
        whichQuery: PropTypes.string
    };
}
```

Hope it will help

Comment: Thank you, I will try it